# Splitting string at special occurrence of character

Tags: python, regex

I have a data file full of strings like this one:

```
1682|Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)|08-Mar-1996
```

I have parsed the strings and split at the `"|"` and dumped it to a list, so I have:

```
['1682', 'Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)', '08-Mar-1996']
```

What I need to do is further split the list at position 1 at the parenthesis that surround the year. If the title of the film didn't have parenthesis in it, I could easily do it, but that's not the case here.

How do I write something that'll skip over the splitting on the parenthesis if the next character isn't a number?  I would like to end up with:

```
['1682', 'Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein)', '1991', '08-Mar-1996']
```

Some help would be fantastic! Thanks

Comment: Why do 2 things in one step? You can just process the element at index 1.

Comment: Will the date always be there after a space?  Is there ever a possibility that the title might look like a date such as for a movie called "1942"?  If the answer to both of these are yes, I would split the reverse of title/date at the space, then trim the ()'s.

Comment: @dansalmo In the data set that I have, yes, the date will always be there. And in my case, there isn't a movie with a year title.

Comment: Doing the split of the reverse would still be more straightforward, but if you are not familiar with regex use, this is a good way to get familiar.

Comment: @dansalmo Doing rsplit("(",1) works perfectly. Thanks for the idea. jwodder did it perfectly below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for *regular expressions!*

```
import re

data = ['1682', 'Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)', '08-Mar-1996']

def handleYear(matchobj):
    data.insert(2, matchobj.group(1))
    return ''

data[1] = re.sub(r'\s*\((\d+)\)$', handleYear, data[1])
```

This removes any string of the form `(dddd)` from the end of `data[1]` and inserts it into the next position in `data`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I call this, then? Rather, how do I call it to get the output I'm looking for? Sorry, a little new at python.

Comment: @Matt.: What more do you need beyond the code I've given you?

Comment: I ran your code, called data and it's no different than the initialization of data

Comment: I ran your updated code. Checked what data was and it still has the original definition of data. What do I need to call to get it to work?

Comment: @Matt.: Ah, typo!  I forgot a plus sign.

Comment: Ah there we go! Thank you so much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28625/discussion-between-matt-and-jwodder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex split:

```
import re
title="1682|Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)|08-Mar-1996"
print re.split('\((\d+)\)', title.split("|")[1])
```

The `re.split` splits on regular expressions, i.e., uses regexes as delimiters. If there is a capture in the split expression, the delimiter is also kept in the split result rather than discarded.

The split expression `\((\d+)\)` first matches literal parentheses `\( ... \)`. and within them matches only digits `\d+`. But we also capture the digits to keep them, hence `\((\d+)\)`.

Comment: This works well, thank you! What does the re.split('\((\d+)\)' portion do? Trying to understand it before there is a space after the end of the movie title. Also, I lose the ending date in the process.

Comment: Tried to clarify the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation - I appreciate that. Makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)'
>>> re.findall('\([0-9]+\)', s)
['(1991)']
>>> re.findall('\((\d+)\)', s)
['1991']
>>>
```

Once you have the year parsed out. you can insert it in whichever index you want to in the list.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. But, in my case, I have a bunch of these strings that I work through at once. Is there a way to not specifically say "(1991)"?

Comment: this regular expression extracts number in the index 1 part of your string i.e. from `'Scream of Stone (Schrei aus Stein) (1991)'`. Can you provide an example of what you are saying? what do you mean "bunch of these strings that I work through at once" ?

Comment: I have a large data file that has 1500 of these lines, which all have different years.

Comment: i dont know what you are saying. this regular expression would work for any year. i.e. it would work for any string which has year in the form `(year)`. did u try this regular expression on those 1500 lines to see if there is a pattern which would not fit in the above regex?